# Plotting points from Data frame onto separate shape file

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, r-sf

Hi I've been working a lot but have not gotten really any clear answers. Basically I have a dataframe with sites and chemical analyses from those sites, whose coordinates I was able to convert into a geometry using st_as_sf. I am also using a separate shapefile named Cave_initial. Now what I want to do is plot the points from the dataframe on top of the shapefile as a single map.

I have tried using geom_sf() but at the very best it plots the points on one graph and then the shapefile as a separate graph. But I need them together.

```
   Master_cave_data <- read_xlsx("./JW_cave_master_version.xlsx", range = "C2:AK85") #dataset containing chemical data and lat/long as numerics
   cave_system <- st_read("./IllinoisCaverns/Cave_System.shp") #shapefile created by colleague 

   Master_cave_data <- Master_cave_data %>%
st_as_sf(coords = c('Long_DD', 'Lat_DD'), crs = 4326, sf_column_name = NULL) 
   #transforming my coordinate data into lat/long
   #due to size of datashet dput will not be advisable to display. New column is created using Long/Lat_DD as geometry. 
   Jul_Data <- filter(Master_cave_data, Month == "Jul") # filtering data for one month

   Jul_Coliform_Data_map <- Jul_Data %>%
   ggplot() + 
   geom_sf(data = Jul_Data$Geometry)  + 
   Cave_initial

   Jul_Coliform_Data_map
```

Comment: please try to give a [mcve] (like plotting a point into a simple shape). It could actually help you to find the answer yourself

Comment: Do you mean an example of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: exactly, with some simple data, so we can actually try your code, reproduce the error it gives and provide a solution

Comment: I edited the question with the mre. I didn't include all the packages I am using because there are a bunch

Comment: I still cannot not reproduce your code and have a plot. Create an example reproducing your problem that we can execute. Please read [mcve]

Comment: I can make a simple dataframe for the master_cave_data but Idk how I can simply the shapefile so that you can reproduce it.

Comment: try creating a toy geometry yourself (a squarre ?) with the same properties than yours (same class), or use an existing package like `rnaturalearth` or similar and choose a country geometry

Comment: The problem with that is that it won't be accurate to my situation because my colleague physically created the shapefile. I think that maybe the problem is that theyre not in the same coordinate system

Comment: That is why creating a minimal example can help you. If you don't reproduce the error, then the problem is in your file, and we can't help you if we don't have it

Comment: One thing to note is in `geom_sf` the `data` call should reference the entire `sf` object, not `sf_object$Geometry`